# Java: Does a Size interface exist?

Tags: java, size

Does some interface like below already exist in Java?

```
interface Size {
    int getWidth();
    int getHeight();
}
```

Edit: It must be an interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend making your own rather than using `java.awt.Dimension`, particularly if what you want is an interface and not a class. If you do want a class *like* `Dimension`, I still wouldn't use it, but instead make another class as an immutable value type... `Dimension`'s mutability is a major weakness. Every method that returns a `Dimension` is forced to return a copy of it, and every method that accepts a `Dimension` is forced to make a copy of it too. Had it been immutable, copying wouldn't have been required in either case.

Answer (score 1):

The Dimension class? http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html

It isn't final, you can extend and overwrite it for your own use.

Comment: @Bozho Fixed it ;) You can also find the link to the abstract class Dimension2D from that page that others have mentioned.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the specific question or is a good idea to use. For one thing, this isn't an interface. For another, `Dimension`'s mutability is a big problem that forces a lot of copying on all Java code that uses it, which shouldn't be necessary if it were an immutable value type as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok using a class and importing an AWT class you can use java.awt.Dimension or java.awt.geom.Dimension2D as an abstract base class.  There isn't a specific interface that I know of though.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat correct answer being given, I'd say my reservations about it. If you are doing a desktop project with awt/Swing - you can `java.awt.Dimension`, although it is not an interface. If you however want it indeed to be an interface - create your own.

Another reason  to define your own `Size` interface, as shown in the question is because with `Dimension` you are creating a dependency on the AWT package. I hope that in the future internal dependencies in the JDK will be minimized and you will be able to run your server-side code without the need to include awt dependencies at all.

So ultimately my answer is - create your own interface.